# Container API cannot connect to container Redis: RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, redis

I'm trying to connect to a Redis database through a Java application, but I'm getting the following error:

> org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

This is my docker-compose:

```
version: "2.1"

services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    image: xpto/game
    build:
      context: .
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: docker
      APP_DATABASE_HOST: redis
      APP_DATABASE_PORT: 6379
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - web
    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    hostname: redis
    image: redis:latest
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - web
```

And this is my application.properties:

```
spring.cache.redis.host=${APP_DATABASE_HOST}
spring.cache.redis.port=${APP_DATABASE_PORT}
```

I also set up a container with a Redis client (Redis Commander) and managed to connect successfully. Only the container running the Java API doesn't work

Comment: Where do you define network `web`?